# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access request header fields after connection is set

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception, android-networking

I am downloading an image file from server using normal Thread and getting `IllegalStatementException`

[image: this the log]

and this is the method I am calling from a background Thread

[image: method].

Hint: I am on a `Fragment` not in `Activity`.

Comment: Are you downloading image from server use Glide library?

Comment: @R2R obviously not. He is doing basic HttpConnection

Comment: Can you please check and say on which line the exception is occuring

Comment: the exception is occurring at 115 line and 180 line first one is during inputstream = connection.getInputerStream() and the second one is during download image method call from background thread

Answer (score 3):

Just put the method `getInputStream()` before the method `getContentLength()`:

```
inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
int fileSize = connection.getContentLength();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add code:

```
connection.getResponseCode();
```

before:

```
connection.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before get the InputStream we have to check if the connection was succesful:

```
if(connection.getResponseCode() == 200 /*Successful connection*/) { //To avoid ".IllegalStateException: Cannot access request header fields after c
  ...
  ...
  connection.getInputStream();
  ...
  ...

}
```